# Influence of Bible in the French Language (à la King James Version in the English Language)

Tags: histoire, littérature, évolution, religion

> The **Authorized Version** has been called "the most influential version of the most influential book in the world, in what is now its most influential language", "the most important book in English religion and culture", and "the most celebrated book in the English-speaking world".
>
> David Crystal has estimated that it is responsible for 257 idioms in English; examples include feet of clay and reap the whirlwind.
>
> Furthermore, prominent atheist figures such as Christopher Hitchens and Richard Dawkins 2 have praised the King James Version as being "a giant step in the maturing of English literature" and "a great work of literature", respectively, with Dawkins then adding, "A native speaker of English who has never read a word of the King James Bible is verging on the barbarian".

Source : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#Influence

Is there a French Translation of Bible (or other religious text for that matter) that had such influence in the French Language/Litterature?

Comment: An important factor here is that Latin remained the liturgical language in France for much longer than in Britain (which split with the Catholic church) and longer than in Germany (where Luther's translation of the bible is often credited as creation of the modern German, replacing many dialects.)

Comment: @RogerVadim Very useful comment. Thank you very much!

Comment: As examples, *Que la lumière soit* is used in grammars as an example of using subjunctive, whereas *Et dieu créa la femme* is the name of a classic movie by Roger Vadim, starring BB (Vadim was a Russian Orthodox who converted to Catholicism in order to marry BB - he cites studying cathechism for the conversion as a background for coming up with the title, but I am not sure though which Bible translation he used.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je me permets de transformer les commentaires en réponse. Merci @Roger Vadim.

An important factor here is that Latin remained the liturgical language in France for much longer than in Britain (which split with the Catholic church) and longer than in Germany (where Luther's translation of the bible is often credited as creation of the modern German, replacing many dialects.)

As examples, *Que la lumière soit* is used in grammars as an example of using subjunctive, whereas *Et dieu créa la femme* is the name of a classic movie by Roger Vadim, starring Brigitte Bardot (Vadim was a Russian Orthodox who converted to Catholicism in order to marry BB - he cites studying catechism for the conversion as a background for coming up with the title, but I am not sure though which Bible translation he used.)